# How to read only 5 records from s3 bucket and return it without getting all data of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3

Hello guys I know lots of similar questions i'll find here but i have a code which is executing properly which is returning five records also my query is how should i only read the entire file and atlast return with desire rows just supose i have csv file which have size in gb so i don't want to return the entire gb file data for getting only 5 records so please tell me how should i get it....Please if possible explain my code if it is not good why it is not good..
**code:**

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import pandas as pd

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'something'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'something'
BUCKET_NAME = 'something'
Filename='dataRepository/source/MergedSeedData(Parts_skills_Durations).csv'

client = boto3.client("s3",
                     aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                     aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
obj = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=Filename)
Data = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
# data1 = Data.columns
# return data1
Data=Data.head(5)
print(Data)
```

This my code which is running fine also getting the 5 records from s3 bucket but i have explained it what i'm looking for any other query feel free to text me...thnxx in advance

Comment: does `obj['Body']` point to the csv file path that is to be read?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yes its get the csv file content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pandas capability of [reading a file in chunks](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking), just loading as much data as you need.

```
data_iter = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], chunksize = 5)
data = data_iter.get_chunk()
print(data)
```

Comment: please can u explain it to me how does it help me to not to get all data from s3 bucket

Comment: if `obj` itself does no do any reading, Specifying a chunksize utilizes the file handler to only read portions of a file as needed. This is essentially how file handlers read through the data in files, they can function as iterators. The chunksize argument gets you an iterator, and you can iterate through it to get only as much data as you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a  HTTP `Range:` header ([see RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35)), which take a byte range argument. S3 APIs have a provision for this and this will help you to NOT read/download the whole S3 file.

Sample code:

```
import boto3
obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object('bucket101', 'my.csv')
record_stream = obj.get(Range='bytes=0-1000')['Body']
print(record_stream.read())
```

This will return only the byte_range_data provided in the header.

But you will need to modify this to convert the string into `Dataframe`. Maybe `read + join` for the `\t` and `\n` present in the string coming from the `.csv` file

Comment: its good only for the very small file where ppl have enough time for counting the file words but this will become painfull when i use it for very large file cause no one will count the number of words in the csv file as simple we will pass only rows no it will give the desire row ....anyway thnx for the answer