# Load CSV file into Pandas from s3 using chunksize

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

I'm trying to read a very big file from s3 using...

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs
df = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket-name/filename', chunksize=100000)
```

But even after giving the chunk size it is taking for ever. Does the `chunksize` option work when fetching file from s3 ? If not is there any better way in loading big files from s3?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396938/how-to-read-only-5-records-from-s3-bucket-and-return-it-without-getting-all-data/55397464) help?

Comment: yeah. thinking Dask is a good option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Clearly says that

> filepath_or_bufferstr, path object or file-like object Any valid
> string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid URL
> schemes include http, ftp, s3, gs, and file. For file URLs, a host is
> expected. A local file could be: file://localhost/path/to/table.csv.
>
> If you want to pass in a path object, pandas accepts any os.PathLike.
>
> By file-like object, we refer to objects with a read() method, such as
> a file handle (e.g. via builtin open function) or StringIO.

When reading in chunk, pandas return you iterator object, you need to iterate through it..
Something like:

```
for df in pd.read_csv('s3://<<bucket-name>>/<<filename>>',chunksize = 100000):
    process df chunk..
```

And if you think it's because the chunksize is large, you can consider trying it for the first chunk only for a small chunksize like this:

```
for df in pd.read_csv('s3://<<bucket-name>>/<<filename>>',chunksize = 1000):
    print(df.head())
    break
```

Comment: This answer helped me. I wrote a function whereby I know the Athena results S3 location as bucket and key. Then I process the massive Athena result csv by chunks: 

`def process_result_s3_chunks(bucket, key, chunksize):
    csv_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    body = csv_obj['Body']
    for df in pd.read_csv(body, chunksize=chunksize):
            process(df)
 `